# python verify external processes in the unix/linux os layer

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

I am trying to create some ourside instances of an application from my python code by using subprocess. I am interested to limit the processes that my code is opening by checking if the process is already running in the os layer (inside docker).

Can somebody who has experience with executing other applications through python and maintaining those external processes ?

Thank you in advance !!

P.s. I could use env variable to store what is already running but after thinking more thoroughly I actually need to check the processes themselves and re-initiate them if they failed

I tried subprocess.check_output but I cannot actually extract what I need from there as all the processes are running with the same flags, only one flag is different and I want to find that only process. 
I tried also os.popen to run ps -ef and run a long pipe to clean the output but I am not satisfied with this.

`print(os.popen( "ps -aef | grep -i 'myprocess' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ print $3 }'" ))`
`subprocess.check_output("ps -ef|grep "+filebeatx, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)`

I expect to be able to search for a process by name and flag and start it again if it failed

Comment: This may be a silly question, but (depending on what distro you're using) why don't you let init/upstart/systemd take care of the restarting?

Comment: I'm running this in docker